# Чем отличается компилятор от интерпретатора?

Tags: javascript, компилятор, интерпретатор

JavaScript к какому языку относится? интерпретируемый либо комплируемый?

Comment: есть интерпретаторы, есть компиляторы.

Comment: А компиляторы могут выполнять переведенный машинный код?

Comment: компиляторы ничего не выполняют

Comment: Можно ссылку на документацию?

Comment: Так как у одного и того же языка может быть как компилятор, так и интерпретатор - то лучше говорить не о компилируемом/интерпретируемом языке, а о конкретной реализации языка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Интерпретатор** - программа которая выполняет исходный код по инструкциям(строчно).

**Компилятор** - программа которая анализирует и переводит исходный код в машинный язык программирования <s>и выполняет его</s>.

Comment: А компиляторы могут выполнять переведенный машинный код?

Comment: >  и выполняет его.

Comment: @Developer Выполнение кода в задачи компилятора не входит. Тем более, что машинный код выполняет непосредственно процессор. Но сама программа, в составе которой есть компилятор, может после компиляции его сразу запустить. Хотя все гораздо сложнее, компилятор не обязательно делает именно машинный код, он может делать какой нибудь промежуточный код, который будет выполнять кто то другой

Comment: Спасибо всем за дополнения!

Comment: Компилятор может сделать код, который будет исполнять интерпретатор. Наверное в каком то смысле процессор компьютера можно считать интерпретатором. Получается что интерпретатор это платформа исполнения, а компилятор это программа для создания кода для этой платформы из другого кода.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript относится к динамически транслируемым языкам (JIT - Just-In-Time). Т.е. он сначала запускается в интерпретируемом режиме, а потом компилируется в нативный код (т.е. код, исполняемый непосредственно процессором).

Вообще разница между компилятором и интерпретатором довольно размыта, но в целом можно считать что основной задачей компилятора является трансляция программы в ассемблер или сразу исполняемый код целевого процессора. Задачей интерпретатора является трансляция в промежуточный код для исполнения виртуальной машиной. Динамические (jit) компиляторы являются некоторой смесью этих двух видов трансляции.